# Why is my $watch function returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, watch, angularjs-watch

Here is my watch function, below... it's currently watching a function in my ViewFactory.

```
// Watch for when tagsFilterModal is showing:
vs.$watch('ViewFactory.retrieveSavedViews()', function(newVal) {
    console.log("New Data", newVal);
});
```

The `retrieveSavedViews()` function calls an API and returns data:

```
function retrieveSavedViews() {
    console.log('retrieveSavedViews called...');
    ApiFactory.getViews().then(function(data) {
        if (data.data.status === 'Success') {
            // Store views locally:
            return storeSavedViews(data.data.views);
            // Populate load view dropdown:

        }
    });
}
```

^ you can see above that I return another function `storeSavedViews()`:

```
function storeSavedViews(data) {
    savedViews = data;
    console.log('storeSavedViews savedViews',savedViews);
    return savedViews;
}
```

[image]

How am I using the `$watch` service wrong here?

Comment: `retrieveSavedViews` doesn't return a value.

Comment: Ah, ok yeah I forgot to `return ApiFactory.getViews()` now actually I don't think I need `$watch` I can just wait for a Promise to be returned! Hmm... will continue here a bit then I guess post what I came up with. Feel free to answer with an example of making the `$watch` work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice you - nearly never use $watch on functions. Because then function will launch in each digest cycle. [Look this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/iFrH4YSknIh05MH3lSm8?p=preview).

There is simple `$scope.$watch('test()')`, and you see that `test()` launches if I change another scope variable and you can not control this.

What you should do is to store promise to object: `$scope.object = Service.get()` and watch it.
Quite often you can leave watcher creation to angular and just have in html:

```
<div ng-if="!object.$resolved">Retrieving data...
</div>
<div ng-if="object.$resolved">Got data {{object}}
</div>
```

And if you need some specific actions to be done after async call finishes - you better provide callback function.

Comment: This is the answer, never use functions in `$watch`, I solved my problem above just waiting for a Promise to return, then doing something.